# Live updating of ListView with ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

Beginner with Android here.

I have a MainActivity, which generates a String and send it to an ArrayList (singleton pattern). I also have a HistoryActivity, which will display the contents of the ArrayList.

I have the ArrayList being sent to an Array, and activity_history has a ListView with an ArrayAdapter in HistoryActivity. There are buttons on activity_history that will remove an item from the ArrayList (and recreate the Array) and clear the entire ArrayList. However, the ListView does not update automatically (the activity has to be closed and reopened).

I'm currently trying `((BaseAdapter) historyView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();` (as seen below), but it is not working. Any advice or guidance would be great.

**HistoryActivity.java**

```
public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DataStorage history = DataStorage.getDataStorage();
String[] historyArray;
private ListView historyView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    historyView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.history);
    historyArray = history.getHistory().toArray(new String[history.getHistory().size()]);
    historyView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, historyArray));
}

/**
 * Clear all of history
 */
public void clearHist(View view) {
    history.getHistory().clear();
    historyArray = history.getHistory().toArray(new String[history.getHistory().size()]);
    ((BaseAdapter) historyView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Remove last entry to history
 */
public void clearOne(View view) {
    history.getHistory().remove(0);
    historyArray = history.getHistory().toArray(new String[history.getHistory().size()]);
    ((BaseAdapter) historyView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Change to main view
 */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**activity_history.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"

tools:context="com.mattbraddock.mbcgen.HistoryActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="clearOne"
        android:text="Remove Last" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="Return" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="clearHist"
        android:text="Clear All" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/history"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mattbraddock.mbcgen">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HistoryActivity"
        android:label="Card History"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: ArrayAdapter accepts an Arraylist... Why do you insist on using an array? Also, you don't need to cast the adapter when calling notifyDatasetChanged

Comment: `ArrayAdapter mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, historyArray)` take a reference of the array adapter first. Then try `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @cricket_007 - if I don't cast the adapter, I get "Cannot resolve method" on `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: I see. Well, saving the adapter is a good idea, then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that each time you use

```
historyArray = history.getHistory().toArray(new String[history.getHistory().size()]);
```

you change the reference of the `historyArray` variable to another newly created array, but the adapter still holds a reference to the old array which you passed to the adapter constructor.

My suggestion would be to replace you array with an `ArrayList` and use `clear()`, `add()`, and `addAll()` methods. Also avoid reassigning the `historyArray` if you want to keep the reference to the data of the adapter, and for `notifyDataSetChanged()` to work.

Comment: Simply using my ArrayList rather than creating an Array was enough to fix the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would save a reference to the adapter and use an Arraylist instead of an array.

```
historyView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.history);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, history.getHistory());
historyView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then when you want to update the view, then just modify the adapter.

```
adapter.clear();
```

Or

```
adapter.remove(0);
```